# Custom shipping countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I'm currently working on a custom jquery/javascript countdown timer to indicate how much time a customer has left to buy something before it gets shipped. It's very crude - but it works for me, i'm not a coder per se - in basic.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date();
      var day = now.getDay();
      //var day = 6;
      var day2 = (now.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getDate();
      var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
      var offday = day2 + month;
      var offdayset = false;
      var end;

      if (day >= 1 && day <= 4) {
        end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 15, 30, 0, 0);
      } else if (day == 5) {
        end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 15, 30, 0, 0);
      } else {
        end = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), day, 15, 30, 0, 0);
      }

      var timeleft = end.getTime() - now.getTime();
      var diff = new Date(timeleft);
      var weekday = new Array(7);
      weekday[0] = "Zondag";
      weekday[1] = "Maandag";
      weekday[2] = "Dinsdag";
      weekday[3] = "Woensdag";
      weekday[4] = "Donderdag";
      weekday[5] = "Vrijdag";
      weekday[6] = "Zaterdag";
      var shippingday = weekday[now.getDay()];

      /* Declare an array. */
      var offdays = new Array('2303', '2412', '2512', '3112');
      /* Traverse each of value of an array using for loop to 
      check whether the value is exist in array*/
      for (var i = 0; i < offdays.length; i++) {
        if (offdays[i] === offday) {
          //alert('Value exist');
          offdayset = true;
        }
      }

      if (shippingday == "Zaterdag" || shippingday == "Zondag") 
      {
        shippingday = "Maandag";
      } else if ("" + diff.getHours() + ('0' + diff.getMinutes()).slice(-2) <= 1630 && offdayset == false) {
        shippingday = "Vandaag";
      } else {
        shippingday = weekday[now.getDay() + 1];
      }

      $("#datecountdown").html("binnen " + diff.getHours() + "u " + diff.getMinutes() + "min " + diff.getSeconds() + "sec");
      $("#dateshipping").html(shippingday);
      //below are just for testing purposes
      $("#time1").html(offday);
      $("#time2").html(offdayset);
      $("#time3").html(end);

    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/verzending-bezorging/" class="shippingtimer" title="*wanneer product op voorraad is">
  <p class="shippingtimer"> Besteld <span id="datecountdown"></span> = <span id="dateshipping"></span> verzonden*</p>
</a>

<span id="time1"></span>
<br>
<span id="time2"></span>
<br>
<span id="time3"></span>
```

So far i got the countdown working and the check if it's weekendl; When it's weekend (saturday or sunday) shipping will only be on Monday. However, i can't get the timer to indicate this into a bigger set of hours: i.e After 16.30 on friday Friday will be +72h, Saturday would be + 48 hours, Sunday + 24, untill 16.30 on Monday.

Can anybody lend me a hand?

Comment: So after Friday 16:30, you basically want the difference between `Monday 16:30 - Friday 16:30` ?

Comment: Not understandable. Can I order on a Saturday? Also if you want to test your code with other dates, try `var now = new Date(2017,2,26);
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      var d = new  Date();
      now.setHours(d.getHours(),d.getMinutes(),d.getSeconds(),0);`

Comment: it may helpful https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: The question seems to be detailed enough yet not understandable, maybe he needs another hand

Comment: Sorry, creative mind;

On friday after 16.30 it should countdown to monday 16.30, likewise for saturday and sunday. @Mplungjan They can order on Saturdays, it wont ship till monday though.

Answer (score 0):

I reorganized your code a bit, to make the logic a little bit clearer, I think this might be what you want.

**Edit:**
var shippingDate = new Date(bookingDate.getFullYear(), bookingDate.getMonth(), bookingDate.getDay(), 15, 30, 0, 0);
**bookingDate.getDay() should be bookingDate.getDate()**
var shippingDate = new Date(bookingDate.getFullYear(), bookingDate.getMonth(), bookingDate.getDate(), 15, 30, 0, 0);

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Zondag";
    weekday[1] = "Maandag";
    weekday[2] = "Dinsdag";
    weekday[3] = "Woensdag";
    weekday[4] = "Donderdag";
    weekday[5] = "Vrijdag";
    weekday[6] = "Zaterdag";
    //var bookingDate - the date you book
    var bookingDate = new Date();
    //var bookingDay - the day you book
    var bookingDay = weekday[bookingDate.getDay()];
    //var shippingDay - the day you ship
    var shippingDay = null;
    //var shippingDate - the date you ship
    var shippingDate = new Date(bookingDate.getFullYear(), bookingDate.getMonth(), bookingDate.getDate(), 15, 30, 0, 0);

    //logic to get shippingDay and shippingDate
    if (bookingDay == "Zaterdag") {
      shippingDate = shippingDate.setDate(bookingDate.getDate() + 2)
      shippingDay = weekday[bookingDate.getDay() + 2];
    } else if (bookingDay == "Zondag") {
      shippingDate = shippingDate.setDate(bookingDate.getDate() + 1)
      shippingDay = weekday[bookingDate.getDay() + 1];
    } else {
      //if we book before 15:30, we still can catch today's shipping
      //otherwise +1 day
      if (shippingDate - bookingDate >= 0) {
        shippingDay = "Vandaag";
      } else {
        shippingDate.setDate(bookingDate.getDate() + 1);
        shippingDay = weekday[bookingDate.getDay() + 1];
      }
    }
    //you can deal with offdays with similar logic, I don't know what does shippingday = "Vandaag"; means
    /*} else if ("" + diff.getHours() + ('0' + diff.getMinutes()).slice(-2) <= 1630 && offdayset == false) {
      shippingday = "Vandaag";
    } */

    //I didn't touch your offday logic, you can fill in the gap
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDay();
    //var day = 6;
    var day2 = (now.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getDate();
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var offday = day2 + month;
    var offdayset = false;




    /* Declare an array. */
    var offdays = new Array('2303', '2412', '2512', '3112');
    /* Traverse each of value of an array using for loop to 
    check whether the value is exist in array*/
    for (var i = 0; i < offdays.length; i++) {
      if (offdays[i] === offday) {
        //alert('Value exist');
        offdayset = true;
      }
    }



    setInterval(function() {
      now = new Date();
      var timeleft = shippingDate - now;
      var diff = new Date(timeleft);

      $("#datecountdown").html("binnen " + diff.getHours() + "u " + diff.getMinutes() + "min " + diff.getSeconds() + "sec");
      $("#dateshipping").html(shippingDay);
      //below are just for testing purposes
      $("#time1").html(offday);
      $("#time2").html(offdayset);
      $("#time3").html("bookingdate: " + bookingDate);
      $("#time4").html("shippingdate: " + shippingDate);


    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/verzending-bezorging/" class="shippingtimer" title="*wanneer product op voorraad is">
  <p class="shippingtimer"> Besteld <span id="datecountdown"></span> = <span id="dateshipping"></span> verzonden*</p>
</a>

<span id="time1"></span>
<br>
<span id="time2"></span>
<br>
<span id="time3"></span>
<br>
<span id="time4"></span>
<br>
<span id="time5"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! "Vandaag" means today; I.e: Wednesday at 14:00 = Today, Wednesday at 17:00 = Thursday. Right now (as of this time locally) it should say "Vandaag verzonden" instead of "Donderdag verzonden". It's a step in the right (and better code) direction.

Comment: But it seems that in the current code Shippingday is always a day ahead. I can't find the flaw, but: `if (shippingDate - bookingDate > 0) {` doesn't seem to work correctly, it goes to the next else.

Comment: var shippingDate = new Date(bookingDate.getFullYear(), bookingDate.getMonth(), bookingDate.getDay(), 15, 30, 0, 0); bookingDate.getDay() should be bookingDate.getDate()

Comment: Added some changes in suggested edit; maybe you can work with that?